# Combining randomForests in R, why are the err.rate, mse and rsq components NULL

Tags: r, random-forest, caret

From `?combine` in [randomForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/):

> The confusion, err.rate, mse and rsq components (as well as the
>   corresponding components in the test compnent, if exist) of the
>   combined object will be NULL.

Why are the err.rate, mse and rsq components for the combined NULL? Is there an efficient way to re-calculate these metrics?

I ask because I would like to figure out a way to use the `oob` re-sampling method with the `parRF` model in [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, at least in default setting, the split of objects into bags is lost.

To replicate, you have to train each partial model with `keep.inbag=TRUE`, then predict the training set with `predict(model,trainSet,predict.all=TRUE)` and clip it to out-of-bags using bag splits from `model$inbag`.
Now, you do this for all forests you want to merge, bind and use to calculate the metrics.

*(I'll try to extend this to actual code later)*

Comment: Is it later yet? =)

Answer (score 2):

[According to this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35613/2817), the out-of-bag predictions for the combined object can be calculated as follows, as `predict.randomForest` returns out-of-bag predictions (if `newdata` is not given):

```
set.seed(42)
library(randomForest)
rf1 <-randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE) 
rf2 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE) 
rf3 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE) 

rf.all <- combine(rf1, rf2, rf3) 
predict(rf.all, type='prob')
```

Answer (score 1):

I've posted sample code below which calculates the error rate for the first tree in a classification forecast:

```
library(randomForest)

# Create dataset
y <- factor(rbinom(300, c(0, 1), 1))
x <- matrix(rnorm(300 * 5), 300, 5, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("x", 1:5)))
model_df <- data.frame(y, x)

# Estimate model
rf <- randomForest(y ~ ., data = model_df, ntree = 5, keep.forest = TRUE, keep.inbag=TRUE)

# Calculate error on the first tree
pred <- predict(rf,model_df, predict.all=TRUE)
tree_pred_1 <- pred$individual[ , 1]

oob_idx <- rf$inbag[ , 1] == 0

oob_tree_pred_1 <- tree_pred_1[oob_idx]
oob_tree_actual_1 <- rf$y[oob_idx]

conf_mtx <- table(oob_tree_pred_1, oob_tree_actual_1)
error_rates <- 1 - diag(conf_mtx) / colSums(conf_mtx)
error_rate <- 1 - sum(diag(conf_mtx)) / sum(conf_mtx)
```