# Why do I need bag composition to calculate OOB error of combined random forest model?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

Could someone please explain me the answer of the question already given here:

[Combining randomForests in R, why are the err.rate, mse and rsq components NULL](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14045/combining-randomforests-in-r-why-are-the-err-rate-mse-and-rsq-components-null)

I do not understand the phrase "clip it to out-of-bag" from model$inbag.

Comment: Next time, please just use a comment to ask clarification about some answer.

Comment: data(iris)
rf1 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE)
rf2 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE)
rf3 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE)
rf.all <- combine(rf1, rf2, rf3)
print(rf.all)

Comment: Ok, well, I meant "please add comment under post that troubles you instead of asking a new question linking it". If you want to clarify your post, please use edit option.

Comment: How can I merge outputs from combined models and how to calculate mse, rsq and error rate. Can you please post some sample code to do it for two models each with 10 trees

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each randomForest model consists of decision trees. The number of trees in `randomForest()` function is controlled by the parameter `ntree`. Each tree is built using not all observation, but a sample with replacement. This approach is called "bagging". `model$inbag` is a *n x ntree* matrix, such that the element `model$inbag[i,j]` is 1 if the observation *i* have been used to train *j* tree and else 0. Prediction of response *i* by tree *j* when `model$inbag[i,j]` = 0 is called *out-of-bag*. The *error rate*, *mse* and *r-squared* usually are derived from *out-of-bag* predictions, and thus are unbiased. By default, `predict()` function combines both *in-bag* and *out-of-bag* predictions to output single decision. We need to separate *out-of-bag* predictions from *in-bag*. Thus we use `predict.all=TRUE` as an additional argument, and *out-of-bag* predictions can be accessed through `prediction_output$individual[!model$inbag]`. Such outputs from several combined models should be merged together, and the ensemble prediction value for each *i* should be obtained as the most-voted class (in case of classification) or mean (in case of regression). Then we can calculate combined model statistics using this prediction values and the actual ones. 
You can read the basis of random forest from official site http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm

---

I have to apologise,  I described the default behavior of `predict()` incorrectly. You can invoke the help on it entering `?predict.randomForest`. If we don't pass the parameter `newdata`, the **out-of-bag prediction** is returned. Taking your code, just compare: `table(predict(rf1),predict(rf1,iris[,1:4]))`. I have checked this option in case of combined model - this feature is still present. So really you don't need to care about bagging, but calculate your statistics directly: if classification - `err.rate<- 1-sum(diag(table(predict(rf.all), rf.all$y)))/sum(table(predict(rf.all), rf.all$y))` else if regression - `mse<-mean((predict(rf.all)- rf.all$y)^2); r.squared<-1-sum((predict(rf.all)- rf.all$y)^2)/sum((mean(rf.all$y)- rf.all$y)^2)`.

Comment: How can I merge outputs from combined models and how to calculate mse, rsq and error rate. Can you please post some sample code to do it for two models each with 10 trees.

Comment: Also it is worth to mention that building several random forests with the same algorithm parameters and then combining models into ensemble is equal to building one random forest but with increased number of trees.

Comment: Hi Fosgen, I need to calculate cross validated (10-fold for example) error rate for the same combined object of random forest if you could please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function to generate the confusion matrix after combining trees (parallel execution, etc):

```
getConfusionMatrix <- function(rf) {

    tbl = table(predict(rf), rf$y)
    class.error = vector()

    for (i in 1:nrow(tbl)) {
        rowSum = sum(tbl[i,])
        accurate = diag(tbl)[i]
        error = rowSum - accurate

        class.error[i] = error / rowSum
    }   
    return(cbind(tbl, class.error))
}
```

To use it on the code above:

```
rf.all$confusion = getConfusionMatrix(rf.all)
```